# How OpenSSH converts user input into an xterm sequence and returns it to the user?

Tags: openssh, xterm, pty

I have some doubts about how the terminal works. I connected to a remote server via SSH, and a PTY channel was created on the remote server. However, I'm not sure which programe translates the data I input into sequences that xterm can understand.

How is this process achieved?